# Equivalent statements of Conditional Independence?

Tags: probability

The [wikipedia article on conditional independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence) states that the following two statements are equivalent, but I can't see how one implies the other and vice versa:

$$\text{Pr}(R\cap{B}\rvert{Y})=\text{Pr}(R\rvert{Y})\;\text{Pr}(B\rvert{Y})\tag{1}$$

$$\text{Pr}(R\rvert{B\cap{Y}})=\text{Pr}(R\rvert{Y})\tag{2}$$

Using Bayes's rule, I can rewrite equation 1 as follows:

$$\text{Pr}(R\cap{B}\rvert{Y})=\frac{\text{Pr}(Y\rvert{R\cap{B}})\;\text{Pr}(R\cap{B})}{\text{Pr}(Y)}$$

but that doesn't help me prove equation 2 -- I don't see a pathway to getting a $B\cap{Y}$ and we have no information whether $R$ and $B$ are independent, so I can't rewrite $\text{Pr}(R\cap{B})$ as $\text{Pr}(R)\;\text{Pr}(B)$. Likewise, expanding equation 2 via Bayes's doesn't help me prove equation 1.

I'm sure it's something obvious, but I just don't see it.

Comment: I think your proposed equivalence is true if and only if R and B are independent https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory).

Comment: you are right. Sorry i misunderstood the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\Pr(B \mid Y) \not = 0$, the following statements are equivalent:

$$\Pr(R\cap{B}\mid {Y})=\Pr(R\mid{Y})\;\Pr(B\mid {Y})$$

$$\Pr(R\mid {B \cap Y})\;\Pr(B \mid Y) =\Pr(R\mid{Y})\;\Pr(B\mid {Y})$$

$$\Pr(R\mid {B \cap Y})=\Pr(R\mid{Y})$$

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see where your second line comes from. Doesn't the definition of conditional probability say $\text{Pr}(R\mid{B\cap{Y}})=\text{Pr}(R\cap{B}\cap{Y})/\text{Pr}(B\cap{Y})$? Even so, expanding out all the other conditional probabilities, I can't see how to get your second line.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Are you happy with saying $\Pr(R\cap B) =\Pr(R\mid B)\;\Pr(B )$? Then $\Pr(R\cap B \mid Y) =\Pr(R\mid B\cap Y)\;\Pr(B\mid Y )$ should be seen as the same.  If you insist,  $\Pr(R\cap B \mid Y) = \frac{\Pr(R\cap B \cap Y)}{\Pr(Y)} = \frac{\Pr(R\cap B \cap Y)}{\Pr(B \cap Y)} \times  \frac{\Pr(B \cap Y)}{\Pr( Y)} = \Pr(R\mid B\cap Y)\;\Pr(B\mid Y )$

Comment: I see it now. Marking the question as answered.